# Login php y oracle

Tags: php, oracle

estoy tratando de hacer un login en php con una bbdd de oracle,pero cuando intento logearme me dice que usuario incorrecto.
Que puede estar mal hecho??La conexion a la bdd si funciona correctamente.

```
<?php
    //abrimos sesión
    session_start();

    //CAPTURO LOS INPUTS
    $user=$_POST["username"];
    $passw=$_POST["password"];

    //CONECTAMOS CON LA BBDD
    $conn = oci_connect('usuario', 'passwd', '192.168.4.88/XE');
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }else{
        echo"conexion realizada";
    }


    $resultado = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre='$user' and passwd='$passw'");
    oci_execute($resultado);
    $row = oci_fetch_all($resultado);


    if($row >0){
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (10 * 60);
        header('location:usuario.php');
        exit;

    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrectas.');
        window.location='index.html'</script>";
        session_destroy();
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: intenta pasarle otro parametro a oci_fetch_all asi: `$row = oci_fetch_all($resultado, $res);`

Comment: ya hice la prueba pero nada,sigue igual

Comment: intenta con oci_fetch_array asi: `$row = oci_fetch_array($resultado); if($row != false) {`

Comment: tampoco sirve  jeje

Comment: Entonces el problema puede ser `oci_parse`, puedes investigar como usar `oci_bind_by_name`

Comment: oci_fetch_all pide mas de una variable. Prueba con `$row = oci_fetch($resultado);`

Comment: Por favor, para este tipo de preguntas procura indicar la versión de Oracle database (y de PHP) que estás usando.

Comment: "$row = oci_fetch_all($resultado, $res);", esta es la solución, yo tuve que reiniciar la pc por un problema en base de datos